# Data race occurring in Swift Actor

Tags: swift, actor, swift-concurrency, thread-sanitizer

I found a data race in my Swift app by using the Thread Sanitizer, and so I made my first attempt to fix race conditions by converting the offending `class` to an `actor`. The crash that the race was causing seems to have gone away, but Thread Sanitizer is still saying there's a data race in the code, which I thought should be impossible in the `actor`.

I can't post the entire `actor` here, but here is the code where the race is occurring:

```
actor SampleActor {
    private var things = Set<Int>()
    
    func addThing(_ newThing: Int, seconds: Double) {
        things.insert(newThing)
        Task {
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000))
            self.things.remove(newThing)
        }
    }
}

// Code to cause the race
let sample = SampleActor()
for n in 0 ..< 1000 {
    Task {
        await sample.addThing(n, seconds: Double.random(in: 0...1.0))
    }
}
```

I'm probably going about this the wrong way, but I need to add an object to the `SampleActor`'s set of objects, and have it be automatically removed after some amount of time.

Is there a better way to do this? And what am I missing about the use of `actor` to avoid the data race in this case? Shouldn't `SampleActor.things` be immune to races here because it's a property of an `actor`?

Comment: Remove the `Task {` part in the `actor`

Comment: @loremipsum thanks, but that seems to break the `addThing` function-- the `sleep` needs to be in an async context so that the added items can be removed not in the order that they were inserted.

Comment: Add async to the function

Comment: @loremipsum Okay! I think that did it. I need to run some more tests, but I can accept this as an answer if you post it as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `Task {` part in the `actor`

Add `async` to the function

```
func addThing(_ newThing: Int, seconds: Double) async {
```

Comment: So I guess I was overthinking async/await and `Task`, treating it like the `DispatchQueue.main.async` calls of old. The fixed code is much simpler, cleaner, and correct!

Comment: @RL2000 yes, also keep in mind that one of the greatest things is that you always know exactly where everything is and that you should be able to `cancel` that task On-Demand, That floating task keeps that from happening because you are not hanging on to the `Task`. At the very top where you call the func you should have `let task = Task{}` then you can call `task.cancel()` and stop the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

There is no data race here. This is a bug in TSAN. Reportedly they have been improving its interaction with actors, but as of Swift 5.7.2, at least, there are still issues. E.g., see https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/57902 or https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/57749.

As lorem ipsum said (+1), it is prudent to abandon the use of `Task {…}` in `addThing`, for more concise code that enjoys the benefits of structured concurrency, but that is not the issue here. For the time being, simply avoid using TSAN with Swift concurrency.

Comment: Good to know! Although later comments in the second issue there mention it seems to be fixed. Either way, it seems like the TSAN did help point out poorly written code in that actor, so it seems like a good thing to use, if with a grain of salt.

Comment: Yes, there was that comment about it being fixed, but there is also a subsequent comment about it not being entirely resolved. (That’s why I had the caveat that it “reportedly” has been “improved”.) You have provided yet another example of how it is still broken. If you find TSAN useful, feel free to use it, but, personally, while I used to be a huge advocate of TSAN, I find that any diagnostic tool with false positives and crashes to be far more trouble than it’s worth. I’ve given up with TSAN for the time being. But I’m reasonably hopeful that this will be resolved in a future release.